# Does clerk protect against CSRF for all form requests or just login/sign up?

Tags: security, next.js, csrf, clerk

We need clarification about CSRF security when using Clerk authentication with NextJs

The clerk docs seem to state that using clerk grants CSRF protection as long as we're not mutating data on navigation.

https://clerk.com/docs/security/csrf-protection

> **Do I need to take additional steps to prevent CSRF attacks?**
> You do not, but it is still possible to accidentally make your application vulnerable to XSS attacks.
>
> Because Clerk uses the Lax setting, it is critical to remember that navigation alone should never trigger a mutation in your backend. Otherwise, the user can be tricked into clicking a link that takes an action they did not intend.

- Does that apply to all form posts in our app?
- Does it matter if we post JSON rather than form data?
- Should we use CSRF tokens anyway?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mentioned library, but I should tell that CSRF token is something completely unrelated to payload's shape, content type or such. It's a type of token which is intended for server to distinguish intentional/legitimate requests from an app from forged requests inspired by attackers on user's machine due to automatic sending cookies to domain user was logged in. That's all. There are completely server-side mechanisms like comparing origin/host/referrer, but I think it's not a bad idea to additionally strengthen your security by using tokens. :)

Comment: @ysurilov Sounds like we can rule out the question about the json vs form data then. Yeah, that was my thinking, probably no harm using CSRF tokens in addition, just wondering if it is necessary or not.